# MonoTouch binding type<implementingprotocol>

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.ios

How do you define parameters/returntypes in MonoTouch Bindings of Objective-c parameters that are "types implementing protocol", for example "`UIView<NIRecyclableView>`".

For example, check this header file.

https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/master/src/core/src/NIViewRecycler.h

```
@interface NIViewRecycler : NSObject
- (UIView<NIRecyclableView> *)dequeueReusableViewWithIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
- (void)recycleView:(UIView<NIRecyclableView> *)view;
- (void)removeAllViews;
@end
```

Should I just have the parameters declared as IntPtr? If so, how do I convert a MonoTouch instance to a IntPtr?

Answer (score 1):

In the same header file you have a `NIRecyclableView` class that it inherits from `UIView` and implements `NIRecyclableView` protocol so you might want to return that object instead

```
@interface NIRecyclableView : UIView <NIRecyclableView>

// Designated initializer.
- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString* reuseIdentifier;

@end
```

So the binding of that header would look like this

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface NIViewRecycler {
    [Export ("dequeueReusableViewWithIdentifier:")]
    NIRecyclableView DequeueReusableView (string reuseIdentifier);

    [Export ("recycleView:")]
    void RecycleView (NIRecyclableView view);

    [Export ("removeAllViews")]
    void RemoveAllViews ();
}

[Model]
[Protocol]
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject), Name = "NIRecyclableView")]
interface NIRecyclableViewProtocol {
    [Export ("reuseIdentifier", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    string ReuseIdentifier { get; set; }

    [Export ("prepareForReuse")]
    void PrepareForReuse ();
}

// Here you would do interface NIRecyclableView : NIRecyclableViewProtocol
// But NIRecyclableView already implements reuseIdentifier
// So you just inline the missing method PrepareForReuse
// and you get the same results
[BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
interface NIRecyclableView {
    [Export ("initWithReuseIdentifier:")]
    IntPtr Contructor (string reuseIdentifier);

    [Export ("reuseIdentifier", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    string ReuseIdentifier { get; set; }

    [Export ("prepareForReuse")]
    void PrepareForReuse ();
}
```

A protocol is like hey this object also can respond to this objective-c messages if you want, so you can either manually inline them on the interface definition like we did above or `NIRecyclableView : NIRecyclableViewProtocol` which in this case we don't have to.

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: I understand this, however, Nimbus insists on creating those simple classes for users to implement easily. Throughout the entire (almost?) framework, they user protocols instead of base classes for flexibility. This would work, if, "SampleClass" that inherits from UIView with the protocol NIRecyclableView can be bound as "SampleClass" inheriting from a super class "NIRecyclableView". Is this possible?

Comment: You must implement the protocol yourself, let's think you bind the protcol like I did above with a small modification `UIView DequeueReusableView (string reuseIdentifier);` instead of `NIRecyclableView DequeueReusableView (string reuseIdentifier);`, now you will have a c# type called `NIRecyclableViewProtocol` and now lets think you create your own `UIView` class called `MyOwnUIView : UIView` and you want `MyOwnUIView` to implement `PrepareForReuse ()` method, you would need to do  `MyOwnUIView : UIView, NIRecyclableViewProtocol` and you would override `PrepareForReuse ()` on your class

Comment: implementation so you can add your own logic to the implementation, so now when dequeueReusableViewWithIdentifier gets called on the objective-c side `look at the implementation of dequeueReusableViewWithIdentifier` [here](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/master/src/core/src/NIViewRecycler.m#L82) it will check if your object `MyOwnUIView` responds to `prepareForReuse` message and since you do, it will call it [here](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/master/src/core/src/NIViewRecycler.m#L83). Hope I am answering your question. Alex

Comment: You are inheriting from UIView, so you can't inherit from NIRecyclableViewProtocol, which means that NIRecyclableViewProtocol is probably an interface, in which case, the PrepareForReuse wouldn't be "overridden", it would just be "implemented". With that said, will my return/parameter types of "UIView" automatically be casted to "UIView<NIRecyclableViewProtocol>"? If so, should I create a "helper" interface that has the same signatures as the protocol so I can implement them as an interface and all my custom c# derived views?

Comment: Please read this http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/api_design#Models also I forgot 2 attributes [Model and Protocol ](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/api_design#Models)

Comment: UIView<NIRecyclableViewProtocol> doesnt mean a new type, it means UIView + some selectors/properties,